# Finding the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues, svd

Given a large matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\sigma_1\ge \sigma_2 \ge \dotsc $, I want to determine only a subset of these values, say $\sigma_5,\sigma_8$ and $\sigma_{19}$. Is there an algorithm that can do this, or is finding the top 19 eigenvalues the best that can be done?

Comment: Do your matrix has any special properties? Do you roughly know the values for $\sigma_5$, $\sigma_8$ and $\sigma_{19}$?

Comment: Nope. But feel free to let me know if there are any results assuming any special properties.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167654/fastest-way-to-compute-k-largest-eigenvalues-and-corresponding-eigenvectors-with maybe you can determine the method behind the scenes there.

Comment: I would guess something in the direction Krylov subspace, Arnoldi or Lanczos iteration is required.

Comment: If your matrix is Hermitian there is guarantee that you have your ordered set of eigenvalues, since all of them are real. Also, if you know roughly the values you might try using the shift-invert method. At the end of the day, I think that it might be easier to find the first $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Not sure if you are interested in the theoretical procedure or just for a practical matter. For the latter purpose: If $A$ is real, then using the built-in singular value decomposition in Matlab or Octave sorts the eigenvalues with respect to the desired descending order. Then the desired eigenvalues are simply the corresponding components of the diagonal elements of the obtained diagonal matrix. For example, in Matlab, inputting "[U S V] = svd(A); d = diag(S); d(5); d(8); d(19)" suffices.

Comment: I am looking for a way to avoid the svd and just come up with the required eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing, as far as I know, unless you know approximately the location of these eigenvalues. As for methods that can compute a subset of the spectrum of a matrix, I know only of methods that can produce:

- eigenvalues from "the extremes of the spectrum", e.g., the ones with the largest absolute value, or with the most negative real/imaginary part. For instance Arnoldi / subspace iteration (suitably shifted).
- eigenvalues closest to one given point in the complex plane, e.g., the smallest ones in modulus (closest to zero). For instance (rational) shift-and-invert Arnoldi or the inverse power iteration.
- eigenvalues in a particular region of the plane, for instance $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$. I think FEAST-type methods do this, but I know very little about them.

From what I understand, with FEAST-type methods you can also get a count of the number of eigenvalues in a specified region of the complex plane (via a contour integral), so in case you need a specified eigenvalue from the middle of the spectrum, for instance the 300th, you can run a sort of bisection search: assume (shifting and scaling) that the spectrum of your matrix is in $[-1,1]$ (and that is real, for simplicity). Compute the eigenvalues $\mu$ closest to $\frac12$. Compute the number of eigenvalues in $[\frac12,1]$. If it is larger than 300, look for the eigenvalue closest to the midpoint of $[\mu,1]$, otherwise for the eigenvalue closest to the midpoint of $[-1,\mu]$. Repeat.

I don't think any of this stuff would be competitive with vanilla `LA` Arnoldi if you replace 300 with 19, as in your example. And maybe not even with 300.